# Specific column level substitution

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, columns

If I have a file with columnar entries, is it possible to substitute specific entries from a specific columns only and save changes to the same file??

Example a file `abc.txt`:

```
SR|FRUITS|COLOR|
1|Apple|Red|
2|Mango|Yellow|
3|Orange|Orange|
4|W.Melon|Green|
```

Need to change *Orange* from fruits to *Orange_Edit*. However the Orange from color shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. We can't tell you how unless you show us an example of your input and your desired output.

Comment: Example: A file abc.txt:
SR|FRUITS|COLOR|
1|Apple|Red|
2|Mango|Yellow|
3|Orange|Orange|
4|W.Melon|Green|

Need to change "Orange" from fruits to "Orange_Edit".
However the Orange from color shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in 2 steps with `awk` like

```
awk '{$2="VAL";print}' input_file > temp_file
mv temp_file input_file
```

That will split the input file on white space, substitute the value in the second column (use any other number than 2 for different column) so it will now be "VAL".  Unless you change it with `OFS` the output field delimiter will be a space.  If you want something else you can add, inside the quotes, something like 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}...' to set the output field separator to whatever you want.

If you want the values to be something other than a constant you will have a bit more work to do, but you can adapt this to do it.

To make this work for the edit in your case you can do:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN {OFS="|";} $2~/^Orange$/ {$2="Orange_edit";} {print}' abc.txt > temp_file
mv temp_file abc.txt
```

This first tells `awk` to split fields based on `|` by passing `-F\|`.  Then, we setup our output to also use `|` for the output delimiter (default is space) by making the first block of code (the part that matches BEGIN, a keyword in `awk` that matches the start of execution) and setting our `OFS`, or Output Field Separator.  As Otheus pointed out, we could do `{OFS=FS}` to set the output delimiter to be the same as the input one.

After that we start looking at the lines.  We compare the second field, which is referenced by `$2`, then check if it matches a regular expression by using `~`.  After `~` is the regex we want to match, `^` here means match the start of the field, then we have the string "Orange", then `$` which matches the end of the field.  Since this is a hard coded string Otheus also rightly observed we could just test for string equality here instead and do `$2=="Orange"` and skip the regex processing since it doesn't really do anything this time.  If that match succeeds the block of code in `{}` after it is executed, which will save a new value into the second field.

Finally we execute the last block of code `{print}` for every line, but when our "Orange" match succeeded above we have changed the value of the second field, so it prints with our new value instead of the old one.

`awk` will normally print to the screen (apparently newer `gawk` has an option to streamline this part) so we save that to a file, then move that file back into the original name.

Comment: With newer GNU `gawk`, you can use `-i inplace` for inline editing.

Comment: @terdon thanks, I didn't know awk also had that now

Comment: @EricRenouf ... no... standard `awk` does not have that, newer `gawk` has. Please _always_ write/say `gawk` when refering that extended version or features of it.

Comment: You could write `$2 == "Orange"` instead of the Regexp. And you could do `BEGIN { OFS=FS }`.

Comment: please could you explain in depth how the awk solution above works...  especially from the ~ part.?

Comment: @abhisheknair I updated the answer with explanations for how it's working

Comment: @Eric.. That made things crystal clear...  Beautifully explained... Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -i.bak -F'\|' -aple 's/Orange/Orange_Edit/ if $F[1] eq "Orange"' file
```

or safer version:

```
$ perl -i.bak -F'\|' -aple '$F[1]=~s/^Orange$/Orange_Edit/; $_=join "|",@F' file
```

Comment: Why `-aple`? It's oranges we're dealing with! :P Note that this will just change the 1st occurrence of `Orange`, that might be on a different column.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, it can. But according to OP's input, 1st column is always number.

Comment: A tad safer: `$F[1]=~s/^Orange$/Orange_Edit/; $_=join('|',@F);`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this. The simplest are probably `awk` and `perl`:

1. GNU `gawk`. If you have a relatively recent version of `gawk` installed, you can do inline editing like this:

   ```
   gawk -i inplace -F"|" -vOFS="|"  '$2=="Orange"{$2="Orange_Edit"}1;' file
   ```

   The `-i inplace` tells `gawk` to edit the file inplace, the `-F"|"` sets the field separator to `|` and the `-vOFS="|"` sets the output field separator to `|` as well. The script sets the second field (`$2`) to `Orange_Edit` only if the second field was `Orange`. The `1;` is `awk` shorthand for "print the current line.
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -i -F"\|" -lane '$F[1]="Orange_Edit" if $F[1] eq "Orange"; 
                      print join "|",@F' file
   ```

   The `-a` makes Perl act like `awk` and split lines on the value given by `-F`, saving the resulting fields in the `@F` array. Then, the script sets the second field (`$F[1]`, arrays start at 0) to `Orange_Edit` if its original value was `Orange`. Then, the fields are joined by `|` and printed.
3. If you just want to change the first occurrence of `Orange`, you could simplify and use

   ```
   sed -i 's/Orange/Orange_Edit/' file
   ```

   You could make that a little more robust by only matching whole fields:

   ```
   sed -i 's/|Orange|/|Orange_Edit|/' file
   ```

Comment: @don_crissti of course, but that starts getting more complex than necessary. If I'm dealing with columns, I'll always go for a tool that understands columns natively.

Comment: @don_crissti - to handle the columns *natively*, you could just do: `s/[^|]*/&\\n/2;s/|Orange\n/&_Edit/;s/\n//g`. More simply, to always handle only the first occurrence of *Orange* if it is immediately followed by another: `s/\(|Orange\)\{2\}/\1_Edit\1/`.